# Generating a Cloudfront URL for a file uploaded to S3?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I seem to be having trouble from Amazon's documentation (both general AWS and the .Net API references) how to accomplish getting a cloudfront url for a file uploaded to S3.

I already have C# ready to upload files into our company's S3 into specific buckets and folders.  However, I have been told that due to costs we shouldn't be serving out of S3, we should be serving from the cloudfront.

So after I upload files (via code) to S3, how do I then generate/retrieve a cloudfront url for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the .net specific code, but basically you create a distribution that points to your s3 bucket. The URL you use will be the domain you get back from creating the distribution + the s3 object's name that you want to download. The documentation on this is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/CreateDistribution.html)

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense and puts me on the right path I think